# How to make the image displays right below the text, not behind the next div content?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to StackOverflow, still learning fullstack web-development.
Just started creating my own website and I'm stuck at my image keeps displaying behind the next div's item, not right below the text. :(
Please help me!! Thank you :D

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 text-container">
          <p>
            <h1>laoreet ante eget, vehicula ligula.</h1><br />
            sed odio eu, eleifend aliquet urna. Donec ultrices dapibus ipsum. 
            Suspendisse ac hendrerit augue. Pellentesque massa eros, auctor ac sapien a, lacinia 
            luctus dolor. Proin et eleifend quam. Mauris tristique dictum tellus vitae molestie.
            Praesent
            auctor justo nisl, eu porta leo aliquam at.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img src="images/picture.png" class="picture-container my-picture" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: #ed8d8d;
}

.container {
  height: 500px;
  padding: 80px 0px;
}

.text-container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 80px;
  text-align: right;
}

.picture-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* IMAGES */

.sophie-picture {
height: 450px
}
```

Comment: paragraphs cannot contain `h` elements, it's invalid HTML

Comment: Looks like you forgot to clear the float.

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to use float, I'd strongly recommend you avoid it. With the exception of flowing text around an element I can't think of any reason to use float. Check out [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) and [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout). You'll be a much happier person. If you insist on using floats you'll need to read up on [clearing floats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Floats#clearing_floats).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your HTML code, the "picture-container" class on the IMG element should likely be moved, so it sits on the "col-sm-4"-div above.

I suspect the "my-picture" class on the IMG and the "sophie-picture" class in the CSS should be the same thing ? most likely you've renamed one of them and forgot to do the same in the other file, If so you should rename one so their names match up again.

There's a `</div>` missing at the end of the HTML code here, but i suspect that is likely just the case here because you only pasted part of your HTML document, and not the case in your own version.

The reason your image and text-container overlap is the use of float.

Removing that likely solves most of the issue.

But judging by the col-sm-8 style classnames i'm guessing you're using something like bootstrap ? Those classes apply a whole bunch of CSS (that you don't particularly have to worry about), but they provide the "column(s) within row; row(s) within container"-style of rapidly building a layout. If you're using those classes its best not to mix it with floats, manual width/height and margin statements, or really any significant CSS (just cosmetic only things like colors, font bold/italic, ...). Bootstrap has many classes so you effectively don't have to write any CSS yourself (classes like mb-4 or such for margins for example).

I would suggest using 1 or the other for a given  container:

- either building it the bootstrap-way with container/row/col and then using the margin/color/etc classes from boostrap.
- or writing the CSS yourself, but then not using those bootstrap classes.

Comment: Thank you! I tried taking out the "float" and didn't work, probably because I mixed bootstrap and css together like you said... :'( I don't know why it has to be too difficult but thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact endresult that you're after is, it'd be easy to write down 
a working solution, but then you'd have describe what result you're exactly trying to
accomplish (and in my opinion pick your preference between css or bootstrap).
It'd be a loss of a learning opportunity though.

Comment: My main recommendation, if you're interested in leaning on bootstrap for most of your styling,
is to read the LAYOUT and GRID SYSTEM chapters on the bootstrap docs, 
here's the link to it in the [bootstrap 4.1 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/)
If you use a different version (like 4.0) then use the version-switch on the top of the site to switch.

Comment: Actually, this helped! And I think mainly they were overlapping because some of the divs crashed or something :/ Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

move the h1 tag above the p tag and set margin-bottom on the p tag to 0.  also picture-container has no declared height so overflow:hidden won't do anything there.  aplly overflow:hidden to wrapper.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: #ed8d8d;
  border:solid 2px red;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container {
  height: 500px;
  padding: 80px 0px;
  border:solid 2px blue;
}

.text-container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 80px;
  text-align: right;
  border:solid green 2px;
}

.picture-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}




p{
margin-bottom:0}

/* IMAGES */

.sophie-picture {
height: 450px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 text-container">
          
            <h1>laoreet ante eget, vehicula ligula.</h1>
          <p>
            sed odio eu, eleifend aliquet urna. Donec ultrices dapibus ipsum. 
            Suspendisse ac hendrerit augue. Pellentesque massa eros, auctor ac sapien a, lacinia 
            luctus dolor. Proin et eleifend quam. Mauris tristique dictum tellus vitae molestie.
            Praesent
            auctor justo nisl, eu porta leo aliquam at.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450" class="picture-container my-picture" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: see updated snippet, if that's not fixing the issue you need to better explain the problem

Comment: Thank you!! I think some of the divs crashed or something? it worked when I took out one of the divs!

Comment: please accept answer if it worked you, thanks